# Is a particular vector in the range of a particular linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying linear algebra using MIT's publicly available materials.  This is a question from an early problem set:

Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $99$ with real coefficients.  Define a linear map
    \begin{align}
 T: V \to \mathbb{R}^{1000}, \qquad T(p) = (p(1),p(2), \ldots, p(1000))
 \end{align}
    We are to

```
    1. Find the dimension of the null space of T.
    2. Find the dimension of the range of T.
    3. Determine whether the vector (0,1,0,1,0,1,...,0,1) is in the range of T.
```

Here is what I have done:  We note that for $p \in V$ to be in the null space of $T$, either $p = 0$ or every integer from $1$ to $1000$ must be a root of $p$.  In the latter case, $p$ must be of degree at least $1000$.  As we are restricted to polynomials of degree $99$ or less, we see that the null space of $T$ must be $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$.  Hence the dimension of the null space of $T$ is $0$.

Now note that $\dim V = 100$, and so by the rank nullity theorem we see that the dimension of the range of $T$ must be $100.$

So far, so good.  Now for the last part.  If $T(p) = (0,1,0,1,\ldots, 0,1)$ is in the range of $T$, then $x = 2n + 1$ where $n$ is an integer in $0,\ldots,499$ must be a root of $p$.  So, by the same reasoning we used for the first part of the question, we see that $p$ must be of degree at least $500$, which means that it is not in $V$.  So $(0,1,0,1,\ldots,0,1)$ is not in the range of $T$.

To me, this seems straightforward.  However, at the beginning of Part 3 in the problem set itself, the instructor has written "This one is hard!", which I find disconcerting.  For if the reasoning I have used in for Part 3 is wrong, it seems to me that the reasoning I have used for Part 1 must similarly be wrong.

Am I missing something?

Comment: All your work seems correct to me.

Comment: Maybe it's hard for people who don't have your understanding :-) I haven't seen the MIT course but I am often horrified how much people restrict all of linear algebra to operating with tuples and determinants and then need to call anything else tricky.

Comment: Thanks, though this was the honors course, so I expect that the students were reasonably sophisticated.

Comment: I can tell you exactly what the complaints are going to be from students on each of these questions: "How was I supposed to know that a degree $n$ polynomial with more than $n$ zeros is the zero polynomial?  That wasn't on the syllabus."  "How are we supposed to find the null space?  This isn't a matrix".  "How was I supposed to know that I should find the null space instead of the range?"  "How can we use rank-nullity, this isn't a matrix?!"  "How were we supposed to think to look at the *zeros* of that vector?  That's so random!"

Comment: Granted, it's an *honors* course at MIT, so you'll only get *some* of those complaints.

Comment: Not to mention that the text is Axler, so matrices are not exactly the emphasis.

Comment: @solitaireartist Ah, that'll also make a difference.  In any case: the key "difficulty" was to look at the vector $(0,1,0,1,0,\dots)$ and extract the information "hey, the polynomial must have a lot of zeros!" even though there was no hint that you should do so.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks.  Would you like to write this up as an answer so that I can accept it and you can get the reputation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything. The key "difficulty" was to look at the vector $(0,1,0,1,0,\dots)$ and extract the information "hey, the polynomial must have a lot of zeros!" even though there was no hint that you should do so.  Problems requiring a spark of insight tend to be hard and tend not to feel hard once you've done them.